# Creating a new directory while exporting -- where does it exist?

Tags: linux, bash

I run the code below (following the [installation instructions](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/local.html) for Apache Airflow):

```
~$ export AIRFLOW_HOME=~/airflow
~$ echo $AIRFLOW_HOME
/home/myuseraccount/airflow
```

However when I execute the `ls` command (in the same shell) the `airflow` directory doesn't appear. Could someone explain to me the underlying process of what's going on?

Comment: Perhaps it gets created by the remaining instructions?

Comment: Sure, but where does it exist until then?

Comment: It doesn't. `export` is just creating a variable not a directory.

Comment: To get to understand how the shell works, I'd recommend to at least skim through the Bash guides at ww.tldp.org.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`export` creates an environment variable. The content of any environment variable is a *string*. The fact the string in the variable you created looks like a valid pathname does not mean a directory (in general: a file) with this pathname exists.

You can create a directory with `mkdir`. Example:

```
mkdir /home/myuseraccount/airflow
```

The guide you linked to states:

> Upon running these commands, Airflow will create the `$AIRFLOW_HOME` folder […]

but it says "these commands", i.e. not the `export` command alone. Most likely some later command is supposed to create the directory if it doesn't exist yet.

If the entire guide silently fails to create the directory then it probably means it's a bug (of Aiflow or of the guide).